# How to split dataframes into different dataframes based on one column name values that starts with some prefix?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

How to split dataframes into different dataframes based on one column name say ## sensor_name ## values that starts with some prefix like "RI_", "AI_" in R  so that I can have two dataframes one for RI and another for AI?

I have tried the following code but this works well when I pivot my dataframe.

> map(set_names(c("RI", "AI","FI")),~select(temp_df,starts_with(.x),starts_with("time_stamp")))

[image: original dataframe]

I expect the output to have two different dataframes,

RI_df:

[image]

AI_df:

[image]

It would be great if anyone help me with this since I just started to work on R programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `split` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- split(df1, substr(df1$sensor_name, 1,2))
names(lst1)  <- paste0(names(lst1), "_df")
```

If the prefix length is variable

```
lst1 <- split(df1, sub("_.*", "", df1$sensor_name))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_split(grp = str_remove(sensor_name, "_.*"), keep = FALSE)
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to have multiple objects in the global env.  For that reason, keep it in the `list` and do all thee analysis on that `list` itself

Answer (score 1):

Another approach from `base R`

```
df <- data.frame(sensor_name=c("R1_111","R1_113","A1_124","A1_2444"),
            A=c(1,2,24,4),B=c(2,2,1,2),C=c(3,4,4,2))


df[grepl("R1",df$sensor_name),]

  sensor_name A B C
1      R1_111 1 2 3
2      R1_113 2 2 4


df[grepl("A1",df$sensor_name),]

  sensor_name  A B C
3      A1_124 24 1 4
4     A1_2444  4 2 2
```

Comment: This does not generalize. Real data frame will most likely have thousands of such `sensor_names`

Comment: @Sotos Right! If it is the case, it can be splitted from `_` then sapply function can be applied to the `unique()` of the splitted values. I just wanted to show an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to identify each group. After that you can subset the data to separate the groups. Functions from the stringr package can extract the relevant text from the longer sensor name.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# Sample data

X <- tibble(
    sensor = c("RI_1", "RI_2", "AI_1", "AI_2"),
    A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    B = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
    C = c(9, 10, 11, 12) 
)


# Extract text to identify groups

X <- X %>% 
    mutate(prefix = str_replace(sensor, "_.*", "")) 


# Subset for desired group

X %>% filter(prefix == "AI")
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  sensor     A     B     C prefix
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 AI_1       3     7    11 AI    
2 AI_2       4     8    12 AI
```

```
# Or, split all the groups

lapply(unique(X$prefix), function(x) {
    X %>% filter(prefix == x)
})
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  sensor     A     B     C prefix
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 RI_1       1     5     9 RI    
2 RI_2       2     6    10 RI    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  sensor     A     B     C prefix
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 AI_1       3     7    11 AI    
2 AI_2       4     8    12 AI
```

Depending on what you are doing with these groups you may do better to use `group_by()` form the dplyr package